# How disable `Modern` Section in Extjs-6

Tags: javascript, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6-modern

I'm developing a client side application using [**Extjs-6**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0). I want to develop `Classic` section then `Modern` section. When I build application, [**Sencha Cmd**](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/) build both, Despite I Only change `Classic` View.

**Is it possible when I develop `Classic`, disable `Modern` section, and vice versa**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your app.json and look for toolkit, you need to define there "classic".

On top check whats defined under builds.